# Xcode Outlets No Showing

Tags: ios, xcode, resize, connection, jquery-animate

Im still quite new to Xcode and wonder if someone can point out where Im going wrong with some code I took from a tutorial?

The code is to resize a view and it worked in the tutorial. Ive check numerous times and my code is identical to the tutorial and it builds OK.

The code is below. The trouble Im having is that my outlets aren't showing in the connections inspector - so I can't connect to my storyboard.

Many thanks for any assistance.

h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyViewViewController : UIViewController{
CGRect viewMinRect;
IBOutlet UIView *myView;
}
@end
```

m file

```
#import "MyViewViewController.h"
@interface MyViewViewController ()
@end

#define MAX_SIZE CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)

@implementation MyViewViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


[super viewDidLoad];

viewMinRect = myView.bounds;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload{
[super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:     (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation !=UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)animateView:(id)sender{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8f];
if(CGRectEqualToRect(myView.bounds, viewMinRect)){
    myView.bounds = MAX_SIZE;
    myView.alpha = 1.0;
}
else
{myView.bounds = viewMinRect;
    myView.alpha = 0.5;
}
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
@end
```

Comment: Is the class of the view in Interface Builder set to `MyViewViewController`?

Comment: It wasn't but it is now and its showing the connections now.
Thank you

Comment: Hi again - Im having another problem that I can't seem to figure out. When I open in iOS sim and click the control I get the message "ResizeAnimation[453:60b] Unknown class ViewController in Interface Builder file."
I can't seem to find why this is.
Many thanks

Comment: Best to ask a new question to get it looked at be a lot of devs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the class of the view in Interface Builder set to `MyViewViewController`? If not change it to `MyViewViewController`.